# How to execute a command for every line in file?

Tags: perl

```
open my $directory, '<', abc.txt 

chomp(my @values = <$directory>);
```

There is a file named `abc.txt` with the following contents:

```
abcde
abc
bckl
drfg
efgt
eghui
webnmferg
```

With the above lines, I am sending contents of file `abc.txt` into an array

Intention is to create a loop to run a command on all the lines of file `abc.txt`

Any suggestions for creating the loop?

Comment: Why is the variable that holds the filehandle called `$directory`? That's pretty ambiguous in an IT context. Use meaningful names for your variables!

Answer (score 3):

```
open my $directory_fh, '<', abc.txt or die "Error $! opening abc.txt";
while (<$directory_fh>) {
    chomp; # Remove final \n if any
    print $_; # Do whatevery you want here
}
close $directory_fh;
```

I prefer to suffix all filehandles with *_fh* to make them more obvious.

`while (<fh>)` loops though all lines of the file.

You might need/want to remove a final `\r` if the file might have Windows/MS-DOS format.

Comment: Actually `chomp` removes whatever is in `$/`.

Answer (score 2):

> create a loop to run a command on all the lines of file abc.txt

```
foreach my $line (@lines){
        #assugming $cmd contains the command you want to execute
        my $output = `$cmd $line`;
        print "Executed $cmd on $line, output: $output\n";
}
```

Edit: As per Sebastian's feedback

```
my $i = 0;
while ($i <= $#lines){
        my $output = `$cmd $lines[$i]`;
        print "Executed $cmd on $lines[$i], output: $output\n";
}
```

OR if you are ok with destroying array then:

```
while (@lines){
        my $line = shift @lines;
        my $output = `$cmd $line`;
        print "Executed $cmd on $line, output: $output\n";
}
```

If you wanted safe code that didn't refer to the array twice, you could use splice in a list assignment.

```
while (my ($line) = splice(@array, 0, 1)) {
        my $output = `$cmd $line`;
        print "Executed $cmd on $line, output: $output\n";
}
```

Comment: The `for` solution loads the whole file contents into memory which could get very huge, `while` loads only a single line (in blocks of Perl's buffer size).

Comment: Correct. I've updated the answer as per your input. Thanks.